# MyEclipse does not highlight matching element

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I'm using `MyEclipse` for development projects. I using a good feature of `MyEclipse` that highlight matching element with a different color but now it doesn't do it and I can't find any setting in `Preferences` window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: Great answer, really thanks. Is there way for without shortcut?

Comment: Yes there is a button in your toolbar: http://i46.tinypic.com/aa8z86.png